# Pycharm Community Edition isn't detecting my packages

Tags: python, python3, pip, python-2.7, pycharm

I have tried and tried again to properly install a package for Pycharm. I've used pip for both Python2.7 and Python3, and I've tried to use the tar file. But Pycharm doesn't detect the modules, even though they work outside of Pycharm. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project, choose

[image]

and now choose System interpreter

[image]

Comment: Please, edit your answer to have image descriptions named accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!